# Json Schema: Validating Arrays

Tags: node.js, jsonschema, ajv

I'm trying to validate a schema that includes two keys, `tags` and `parameters`, which are intended to be arrays of arbitrary key-value pairs.  For some reason, though, I can't get *anything* I specify for these two keys to fail validation (I'm using the nodejs library `ajv`).

Here is the schema definition:

```
var cfStackSchema = {
  name: { type: "string" },
  application: { type: "string" },
  account: { type: "string" },
  environment: { type: "string" },
  tags: { 
    type: "array",
    items: {
      type: "object",
      patternProperties: {
        "^[a-zA-z0-9]$": { type: "string" }
      },
      additionalProperties: false
    },
    additionalItems: false
  },
  parameters: { 
    type: "array",
    items: {
      type: "object",
      patternProperties: {
        "^[a-zA-z0-9]$": { type: "string" }
      },
      additionalProperties: false
    },
    additionalItems: false
  },
  deps: { type: "array", items: { type: "string" } },
  required: ["name", "account", "environment", "parameters", "application"]
};
```

And here is a test object. I'm passing `parameters` here as a simple string, intending it to fail validation, but it actually passes:

```
var spec = { name: "test", 
            account: "test", 
            environment: "test",
            parameters: "test",
            application: "test"
          };
```

Here is the code I'm using to validate:

```
  var ajv = new Ajv({ useDefaults: true });
  var validate = ajv.compile(cfStackSchema);
  if (!validate(spec)) {
    throw new Error('Stack does not match schema!')
  }
```

Comment: please include the code you are using to validate, as that is most likely where the problem is

Comment: Thanks. It has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put the properties inside of a `properties` object

```
var cfStackSchema = {
  properties: {
    name: { type: "string" },
    application: { type: "string" },
    account: { type: "string" },
    environment: { type: "string" },
    tags: { 
      type: "array",
      items: {
        type: "object",
        patternProperties: {
          "^[a-zA-z0-9]$": { type: "string" }
        },
        additionalProperties: false
      },
      additionalItems: false
    },
    parameters: { 
      type: "array",
      items: {
        type: "object",
        patternProperties: {
          "^[a-zA-z0-9]$": { type: "string" }
        },
        additionalProperties: false
      },
      additionalItems: false
    },
    deps: { type: "array", items: { type: "string" } },
  },
  required: ["name", "account", "environment", "parameters", "application"]
};
```